# Academic Knowledge Cognitive Services Labs API error 500

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, internal-server-error

I have obtained API keys for the Cognitive Services Labs by Microsoft [here](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions), but when I try using  the example provided in [the API "Try me" page for the `graphSearch` method](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/57e3569ddbe2d91158fa270e), I get a 500 server error after about 20 seconds. Other API endpoints (`interpret`, `evaluate`) seem to be working well. Here's my query (also tried via the "Try me" page):

```
export SERVER=api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com

curl "https://${SERVER}/academic/v1.0/graph/search?mode=json" \
    -H "Host: ${SERVER}" \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${API_KEY}" \
    --data '{"path":"/paper/AuthorIDs/author","paper":{"type":"Paper","NormalizedTitle":"graph engine","select":["OriginalTitle"]},"author":{"return":{"type":"Author","Name":"bin shao"}}}'
```

I've written an inquiry via the Cognitive Services UserVoice portal but with no answer so far. The service is not listed in the [Azure Status page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/).

I want to know whether my query or account registration is faulty, or is this a temporary problem. Should be easy to answer.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. Did you receive any feedback from your inquiry?

Comment: The blurb on the service says: "Tap into the wealth of academic content in the Microsoft Academic Graph. 10,000 transactions per month, 3 per second for interpret, 1 per second for evaluate, 6 per minute for calcHistogram". I suspect this is the issue. One needs to throttle back API requests, perhaps?

Comment: @aterhorst No. This happens even if I do one request per month.

Comment: @Yuval, I know it's been a long time that faced that problem. I am currently trying to work on similarity api, but the response is same "500 internal server error". How did move on, did you find any other way? Please let me know.